# How to dispatch action from async.queue in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need to dispatch the action from async.queue when a certain task of uploading audio started. Async queue is used to upload files concurrently. 
Unable to dispatch from req.on function in the following code.

```
let q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
  uploadFileOnS3(audioName, task).then(function (audioS3) {
    console.log("s3 value is", audioS3);
    let params = { Key: audioName, Body: task.file, ACL: 'public-read' };
    let req = audioS3.upload(params);

    req.on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
      let percentage = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
      console.log("percentage value is", percentage);
      dispatch({type: t.PERCENTAGE, payload : percentage})
    });
  });
}, 1);


export const audioUpload = audioObj => async dispatch => {
  q.push(audioObj);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk)? Then you could dispatch actions asynchronously and do something like

```
export function upload(parameters) {
   return async (dispatch, getState) => {

      dispatch(someTaskAction());

      await dispatch(uploadAction());

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just send the "dispatch" object with the args in the queue.

```
  q.push({ audioName, audioObj, dispatch },()=>{
})
```

and inside queue you can do something like this

```
let q = async.queue(async function (task, callback) {
  uploadFileOnS3(audioName, task).then(function (audioS3) {
    console.log("s3 value is", audioS3);
    let params = { Key: audioName, Body: task.file, ACL: 'public-read' };
    let req = audioS3.upload(params);

    req.on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
      let percentage = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
      console.log("percentage value is", percentage);
      task.dispatch({type: t.PERCENTAGE, payload : percentage}) //here
    });
  });
}, 1);
```